# Button in Laravel Datatable not rendering

Tags: php, laravel, datatables, laravel-5.4

I'm using Laravel 5.4 and Yajra datatable, below is my code working properly but in the 2nd action I've created, The button is not displaying but instead it display the text itself "`<a href="/product/'. $row->id .'/create-price" class="btn btn-primary">Add Price</a>`" What am I missing ?

```
public function getProductDatatable()
    {
        $Product = Product::query();
       return Datatables::eloquent($Product)
        ->addColumn('action', function($row) {
            return '<a href="/product/'. $row->id .'/edit" class="btn btn-primary">Edit</a>';
        })

        ->addColumn('add_price', function($row) {
            return '<a href="/product/'. $row->id .'/create-price" class="btn btn-primary">Add Price</a>';
        })

       ->make(true);
    }
```

Frontend Part

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $('#product-table').DataTable({
                processing: true,
                serverSide: true,
                ajax: '{{ url('product/get_product_datatable') }}',
                columns : [
                    {data: 'id', name: 'id'},
                    {data: 'product_code', name: 'product_code'},
                    {data: 'action', searchable: false, orderable: false},
                    {data: 'add_price', searchable: false, orderable: false},
                    {data: 'created_at', name: 'created_at'},
                    {data: 'updated_at', name: 'updated_at'}
                ]
            });
        }); 
        </script>
```

Comment: how do you render the view in the front end

Comment: @meda I already edited my question and added the frontend js

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to define `rawColumns` :

```
public function getProductDatatable()
    {
        $Product = Product::query();
       return Datatables::eloquent($Product)
        ->addColumn('action', function($row) {
            return '<a href="/product/'. $row->id .'/edit" class="btn btn-primary">Edit</a>';
        })

        ->addColumn('add_price', function($row) {
            return '<a href="/product/'. $row->id .'/create-price" class="btn btn-primary">Add Price</a>';
        })
       ->rawColumns(['add_price', 'action'])
       ->make(true);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I found this [issue on github](https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables/issues/949), try adding `rawColumns`

```
 Datatables::eloquent($Product)
 ->addColumn(..)
 ->rawColumns(['add_price']);
```